# Set a parameter Value of Function Js

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

PROBLEM =>
I WANT TO ADD VALUE OF PARAM CAPACITY BUT I WANT ALSO NAME PARAM TO BE DEFAULT

```
function Js(name = 'Mango' , capacity = 40){
console.log(`${name} with a capacity ${capacity} will be delivered !!!`)
}
Js() // .... Correct
Js("Something" , 40) // .... Also Correct
```

But What if i want to just give value to capacity and set name default

Like this =>

`Js( ..., 55) // Mango with a capacity 55 will be delivered !!!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put default argument on second place.

```
function Js(capacity, name= 'Mango'){
console.log(`${name} with a capacity ${capacity} will be delivered !!!`)
}
Js(40) //"Mango with a capacity 40 will be delivered !!!"
Js(40, 'Something else') // "Something else with a capacity 40 will be delivered !!!"
```

Comment: Good Answer but I know that what if capacity param is optional ?

Comment: Depends what you want to happen when capacity is not passed. It will return undefined so you can do some logic inside function like if statement or something to manipulate it. Or if it is simple you can just do ternary conditional ternary operator.

Comment: No i want it to be like function J(name = "" , capacity = 40){....} // It will not return undefined..

Comment: I do not understand what do you want... Do you want name optional and capacity default value? You want both to have default value? I meant **capacity** will return undefined in my example above if you do not pass any arguments to function...

Comment: I want both optional 

Comment: okay then give them both default values.

Comment: So , what if a user enter the value of capacity first like this `Js(40)` both args are optonal  but capacity is 2nd arg and he entered only this so then i want name will be the default and capacity will be this

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/sinisa92/zkwpdrum/1/